# Magento2 Rest Api login customer using Website Id?

Tags: magento2.3

I am using login API magento2 but I want to use customer log in using website id
In URL/rest/Store_code/V1/integration/customer/token if I am using store code it's working but want use website id does not store code

In Body

```
{"username":"test@test.com", "password":"Abc@123456","website id":2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Website has unique URL,  just use url where website id : 2,
And that API only accept two parameters : username and password.
Also you can rewrite `Magento\Integration\Model\CustomerTokenService`

```
<preference for="Magento\Integration\Api\CustomerTokenServiceInterface" type="Magento\Integration\Model\CustomerTokenService" />
```

createCustomerAccessToken() to get more parameters.

Comment: but in magento1 we bare able to do this

Comment: I don't know magento 1, you can check here , list of rest api for magento 2 : https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/